# How are bytes represented and converted from one format to anoter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have bytes in Python: `b'P\xf3g9\xea\xc3'`

I know that this is an IP address and I know how to convert it to one (this is based on [BitTorrent specification](https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_Response) -> "the **peers** value may be a string consisting of multiples of 6 bytes. First 4 bytes are the IP address and last 2 bytes are the port number. All in network (big endian) notation."):

```
import socket
import struct

p = b'P\xf3g9\xea\xc3'

print(f'peer {p}: bytes IP: {p[:4]}; bytes PORT: {p[4:]}')
# > peer b'P\xf3g9\xea\xc3': bytes IP: b'P\xf3g9'; bytes PORT: b'\xea\xc3'

print('IP', socket.inet_ntoa(p[:4]))
# -> IP 80.243.103.57

# > - big-endian; H - unsigned short
print('PORT', struct.unpack(">H", p[4:])[0])
# -> PORT 60099
```

I'm struggling to understand how this works? Ideally I would like to understand how to convert `bytes` to the IP address by hand.

Some questions that I have:

- what is the leading `P` in bytes?
- how to transform this represntation (i assume it's hex?) to base 2?
- I think I understand `\xf3` -> that translates to `243`. What abaout `g9`?

Would be great if some one could explain or point somewhere where I can read more about it.

Comment: Each element of a `bytes` object is an integer.

Comment: Check out the docs: [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) and [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings). BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Comment: To give you a partial answer at least, `P` and `g9` are bytes: 0x50 and 0x67 0x39. They just happen to be representable as text.

Comment: `g9` translates to hex `6739`, or in decimal `109,57`. Python prints high ASCII codes as escaped hex sequences, but lower codes need no escaping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python bytes representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52688418/python-bytes-representation)

Comment: @MadPhysicist that's a little misleading. The bytes object really has a raw buffer of bytes, however, the choice was made that *indexing* into a bytes object would give you back an `int` object, but that is a conversion that happens on the fly. I think it was due to it being "usually" what you want, although there is a PEP to add methods to return a bytes object representing an individual byte. Slices have always returned bytes

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Thanks for the clarification. My comment was hasty at best. The goal was to point OP to the type of interest more than anything at that point.

Comment: thanks all! feels like there's some reading ahead of me! If someone would put this as an aswer I would happily approve it.

Comment: One more question that relates to @usr2564301 comment. Why does Python print high ASCII codes as escaped hex sequences, but lower codes need no escaping? Do other scripting languages do this as well? Is it pretty standard? BTW adding all your comments together I'm starting to piece this together. Thanks!